# I'm getting an error in my .asp file, and I don't know how to solve this (I don't know ASP). The error what i'm getting is the following

Tags: asp.net, .net

ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/Index.asp, line 216

**and line 216--**

```
<%ip=0
        set rsEx=conn.execute("select * from products where featured=1")
        while not rsEx.eof
        ip=ip+1
        set rsMasSku=conn.execute("select top 1* from productSkus where masterid="&rsEx("id")&" order by price")
        dprice=rsMasSku("dprice")  
        price=rsMasSku("price")
        if cDbl(dprice) > 0 then
        finalPrice=cDbl(price)-cDbl(price)*cDbl(dprice)/100
        else
        finalPrice=price
        end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the source of your error is this code block:

```
set rsMasSku=conn.execute("select top 1* from productSkus where masterid="&rsEx("id")&" order by price")
dprice=rsMasSku("dprice")  
price=rsMasSku("price")
```

What happens now is that if the second rsMasSku recordset does *not* return data for the given rsEx("id") value, the references to rsMasSku("dprice") or rsMasSku("price") do not exist at all, and an error is returned.

So the solution would be to add an EOF check (similar to the `while not rsEx.eof` *after* the instantiation of the rsMasSku recordset:

```
set rsMasSku=conn.execute("select top 1* from productSkus where masterid="&rsEx("id")&" order by price")
if not rsMasSku.EOF then    
    ' ... now you can access the rsMasSku fields et cetera ...
else
    ' ... do nothing ... or maybe think of something else to do ...
end if
```

Comment: Hi Thailo, thanks for helping, but my website footer not showing in website home page.. and inner pages it's showing..

Comment: That is logical. After the error occurs, the rendering of the page stops. So you should first add the if-else logic I suggested and then move on to the next error, if any.